# Intranet with custom Workflows in OpenAtrium/Drupal

Tags: drupal, workflow, open-atrium

I've been reading about building an intranet site with different frameworks and I've found Open Atrium to be a great alternative since it's *naturally* oriented to that use.

I'd love to add some custom workflows associated with personnel management, for example, each team member gets a reminder every Friday to fill out a form with the hours of the week dedicated to each project. Once submitted, the role 'administrator' gets notification of all the forms received and of those not received, the details of each one and the sum of hours per 
project. Any insight on how to proceed with this implementation would be greatly appreciated.

I've searched but haven't found a module that has this kind of workflow. How would this be implemented with cck, views or fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to create the first part: emailing users to remind them to fill in their forms.  The rules module has a 'Send mail to all users of a role' action which you can use.

I would use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create a new view of the filled in forms (which I assume will just be nodes of a certain content type) and make that view accessible only to the administrator in the view's 'Access' section.  Views are quite powerful, and you'll probably be able to do most all of what you require with them, but it's hard to be more specific without knowing which version of Drupal you're using and any more details about the problem (such as, will this form users are filling out really be just a node or a webform?).  As an example of a views feature: if you go to add a field to your view, you should be able to see a ' Global: Math expression' field, where you can do things like add previous fields together, etc.

On the other hand, if you use the [Webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform) to build the form users have to fill out, that can send an email automatically each time it's submitted and the responses can be downloaded into an excel file by the administrator to manipulate further.

Hope some of those ideas help!